# dynamic column and rows with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

My input parameter for the code below is just a tablename,

I was able to query the data return in json format,
 however, i am not able to display my rows item of data.
 any idea what did i do wrong?

```
<script>
var invtype = "@ViewBag.invtype";

    function ViewModel() {  

        var self = this;
        function ColName(tbstruct){ 
            this.ColumnName = tbstruct.ColumnName
        }

        self.TBStruct = ko.observableArray(); 
        self.items = ko.observableArray(); 

        self.invtype = invtype;

        self.Load = function () {


    //expected data for self.items
    //[{"$id":"1","Id":2,"Inv_Id":"PV0001-1","ACX_No":"6","ACX_Name":"ABC","S_No":"5", "Acc_Class":"Local","Direction":"Two-Way"},{"$id":"2","Id":2,"Inv_Id":"PV0002-1","ACX_No":"3","ACX_Name":"CKD","S_No":"6", "Acc_Class":"Local","Direction":"Two-Way"}]


            $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Content("~/api/")"+self.invtype, 
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function (data) {
                        // Map the returned JSON to the View Model  

                        self.items = data;
                    }
            });

//expected data
     //[{"$id":"1","ColumnName":"Id","system_type_id":56,"primaryCol":1}, {"$id":"2","ColumnName":"Inv_Id","system_type_id":231,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"3","ColumnName":"ACX_No","system_type_id":175,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"4","ColumnName":"ACX_Name","system_type_id":175,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"5","ColumnName":"S_No","system_type_id":175,"primaryCol":0} {"$id":"27","ColumnName":"Acc_Class","system_type_id":231,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"28","ColumnName":"Direction","system_type_id":231,"primaryCol":0} ]

            $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Content("~/api/inventories/")"+self.invtype,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function (data) {
                        // Map the returned JSON to the View Model  
                        $.each(data,function(i,dt){
                            //console.log(dt.ColumnName);
                            self.TBStruct.push(new ColName(dt));
                        });
                        //console.dir(self.TBStruct);
                    }
            });
            return self;
        };
    } 

    var View = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(View.Load());
```

here i am trying to display them out.

```
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: TBStruct">
            <th data-bind="text: ColumnName"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody >
        <tr data-bind="foreach: items" >
            <td data-bind="text:$data"></td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So the call to `~/api/inventories/` gets you only the column names? How does the result data for the call to `~/api/` look like?

Comment: Tomalak, this is the structure '[{"$id":"1","ColumnName":"Id","system_type_id":56,"primaryCol":1}, {"$id":"2","ColumnName":"Inv_Id","system_type_id":231,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"3","ColumnName":"ACX_No","system_type_id":175,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"4","ColumnName":"ACX_Name","system_type_id":175,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"5","ColumnName":"S_No","system_type_id":175,"primaryCol":0} {"$id":"27","ColumnName":"Acc_Class","system_type_id":231,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"28","ColumnName":"Direction","system_type_id":231,"primaryCol":0} ]'

Comment: Well, that's the data structure from your question. I'd like to see the *other* data structure. Particularly I'd like to see how it looks when there's more than one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.invtype = "@ViewBag.invtype";
    self.columns = ko.observableArray();
    self.rows = ko.observableArray();

    self.load = function () {
        $.when(
            $.get("@Url.Content('~/api/inventories/')" + self.invtype),
            $.get("@Url.Content('~/api/')" + self.invtype)
        )
        .then(function (columnResponse, rowResponse) {
            var columnDefs = columnResponse[0],
                rowDefs = rowResponse[0],
                columnMapping = {
                    key: function (data) {
                        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.ColumnName);
                    }
                },
                rowMapping = {
                    key: function (data) {
                        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.Id);
                    }
                };

            ko.mapping.fromJS(columnDefs, columnMapping, self.columns);
            ko.mapping.fromJS(rowDefs, rowMapping, self.rows);
        });

        return self;
    };
}
```

Notes:

- Using jQuery's `.when()` and `.then()` ensures that view model processing occurs only after both HTML requests have returned successfully. See [jQuery's documentation on the topic](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).
- The `key` function in the custom mapping ensures that when you call `load()` again then only the appropriate parts of your view model get an update. Otherwise `ko.mapping.fromJS` will replace the entire observable, resulting in a complete re-build of the affected part of your page. Specifying `key` allows partial page updates, so use a unique property of your data here. (If you don't plan on refreshing data from the server during page life time this step might not be necessary.)
- The use of `ko.utils.unwrapObservable()` is mandatory because during a load operation `key` will be used on both the existing view model contents *and* the server response, so for example `data.ColumnName` could be an observable or a raw value.
- Be sure to read through the advanced section of the [mapping plugin documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), you might find other helpful bits.

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $root.columns">
            <th data-bind="text: ColumnName"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.rows">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $root.columns">
            <td data-bind="text: $parent[ColumnName()]"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Notes:

- The only place where `$root` is actually necessary is in the `<tr data-bind="foreach: $root.columns">` binding. The others are just included for consistency.
- `$parent` refers to the row from `foreach: $root.rows`.
- The parentheses in `$parent[ColumnName()]` are necessary because `ColumnName` is an observable and in a complex binding they are not unwrapped automatically.

The whole thing can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/A6T8p/
and here (extended version): http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/A6T8p/1

Comment: much more better. Thank you!

Comment: wow this is much more better. Thank you!

i am progressing to create the Create Update Delete access out of this table. (dynamically)

I will need to do some columns filtering where my previous method is

      `function ColName(tbstruct){ 
 this.HeaderName =tbstruct.ColumnName.replace('_',' ')
 this.ColumnName = tbstruct.ColumnName,
 this.PrimaryKey = tbstruct.PrimaryKey,
 this.SystemField = tbstruct.ColumnName.indexOf('SYS'),
 this.Visible = tbstruct.ColumnName.indexOf('SYS'),
 this.HrefDetailsPage = function(item) {  
    alert(invtype + '/' + item.Id); 
 };
     }`

Comment: Above function actually reconstruct the system field name to user friendly output.

Comment: would it be wise for me to reconstruct the field in the var columnDefs?

Comment: @SiGaban I would work with custom child view models and a `create` mapping. You might get some ideas from this: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/A6T8p/1/

Answer (score 3):

rewrote my self.load

```
         self.Load = function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Content("~/api/")"+self.invtype, 
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    // Map the returned JSON to the View Model  
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data,{}, self.items);   
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Content("~/api/inventories/")"+self.invtype,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    // Map the returned JSON to the View Model  
                    $.each(data,function(i,dt){ 
                        self.TBStruct.push(new ColName(dt));
                    }); 
                }
            });
            return self;
        };
```

output with iteration below

```
        <thead>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: TBStruct">
        <th data-bind="text: HeaderName,visible: SystemField == -1 || Visible" ></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: items " >
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $root.TBStruct, click:function() { alert('me');}" id="rowData">
         <td data-bind="text: $parent[ColumnName],visible: SystemField == -1 || Visible" ">
         </td> 
         </tr> 
            </tbody>
```

Comment: +1 right direction. I have a few ideas to improve this, but I would need to see the results of both Ajax calls.

Comment: I am glad to learn.
self.item(data) =  //expected data for self.items
    //[{"$id":"1","Id":2,"Inv_Id":"PV0001-1","ACX_No":"6","ACX_Name":"ABC","S_No":"5", "Acc_Class":"Local","Direction":"Two-Way"},{"$id":"2","Id":2,"Inv_Id":"PV0002-1","ACX_No":"3","ACX_Name":"CKD","S_No":"6", "Acc_Class":"Local","Direction":"Two-Way"}]

Comment: self.tbstruct = //expected data
//[{"$id":"1","ColumnName":"Id","system_type_id":56,"primaryCol":1} {"$id":"2","ColumnName":"Inv_Id","system_type_id":231,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"3","ColumnName":"ACX_No","system_type_id":175,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"4","ColumnName":"ACX_Name","system_type_id":175,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"5","ColumnName":"S_No","system_type_id":175,"primaryCol":0} {"$id":"27","ColumnName":"Acc_Class","system_type_id":231,"primaryCol":0},{"$id":"28","ColumnName":"Direction","system_type_id":231,"primaryCol":0} ]

Comment: Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/A6T8p/. I'm also writing a new answer with a few explanations.